# Calling a web service from the C# console application

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I am trying to call a web service and get the json response in to my application. I created the class for the get set property for the JSON response. Below is what I am trying

```
public class iResponse
{
    public iResponse(){   }
    public List<iDTO> data { get; set; }
}
public class iDTO
{
    public iDTO() { }

    public class Field
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class CForm
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
        public List<Field> fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class IlMetadata
    {
    }

    public class IlResponse
    {
        public List<CustomForm> custom_forms { get; set; }
        public IlMetadata il_metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public IlResponse il_response { get; set; }
    }
```

And trying to call the service like below

```
  public class iAPICall
  {
    string BaseURL= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];
    string accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccessToken"];
    public void Get()
    {
        using (var iab = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
            iab.BaseAddress = uri;
            iab.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            iab.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            iab.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var response = iab.GetAsync(BaseURL).Result;
```

Here I need to get the response from the service call and store them in to string. Like each field in response in to string. How should I proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the content of the response you get :

```
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>().Result;
```

You should also add the async keyword on your `Get` method in order to use the async/await pattern.

Comment: Here result will store entire response but how to get each fields from the response. Do we need to deserialize it?

Comment: Yes you have to deserialize it to have an object instead of a json string